# google chrome не предлагает сохранение пароля

Tags: html, google-chrome

вопрос может и банальный но может кто подскажет что не так, может надо в html к форме что нить добавить, или может есть возможность где нить руками добавить адрес и пароль к localhost?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А у полей "name" указано? Вроде оно от него оттакливается. Аля ```name="login"``` ```name="password"```

Comment: @OliverPatterson там компонента используется((не моя) может быть в ней проблема), напишу руками гляну что как дам знать

Comment: @OliverPatterson по ходу проблема была в браузере